# Any shortcut to get the absolute value of a boolean array?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

Basically what I want to do is find the absolute value of a `boolean` array in Java.

Obviously i know how to code it manually with a for-loop but I am going for efficiency in my algorithm and if there was a built-in way using bit operations (or something, i have no experience with bitfields) that would be much faster probably.

BTW when I say absolute value I mean if my array is `{true,false,false,true...}` then each true would increase the absolute value by 1 similar to a vector in calculus.

Comment: Are you talking about a `boolean[]`, `Boolean[]`, or something else entirely?

Comment: Your definition of "absolute value" is, well, unusual. You should post a sample input with expected output, using actual Java code to better explain what you mean

Comment: For any kind of array, a for loop is the most efficient way of accessing all elements, which is what you want to do.

Comment: Do you want a count of true(s)?

Comment: Yes I want a count of 'true's and I am using just a basic boolean[] array.

Comment: And I already have to code to do it through a for loop I am just wondering if there is an even easier way to do it.
Surely through bits it would be just 1+0+0+1+...=abs value
and no the definition is pretty standard. absolute value is usually used to denote the cardinality of a set, in this case i want to exclude all values that are zero

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `java.util.BitSet`. It provides a method `cardinality` that counts the number of set bits.

Comment: How would I implement this?
just add the import then if I have
boolean[] myBooleanArray = {blah blah blah}

int absVal = myBooleanArray.cardinality
like length for int arrays

Comment: Makes only sense, if you can use a `BitSet` instead of the boolean array.

Comment: woudl I have to change everywhere in my code that uses the array?

Comment: Yes. If this cannot be done, I guess, the for loop is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I think following code could give you the result that you expect.

```
public static int countTrues(boolean[] array) 
    {
    return new Integer(StringUtils.countMatches(Arrays.toString(array).
    replace("true","1").replace("false", "0"),"1"));
    }
```

Above code uses the awesome functions provided in the StringUtils class in the Commons jar.
I tried it on a small sample data. It works fine.